# MyBatisGenerator failed to run with 'http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/property/accessExternalDTD' is not recognized

Tags: java, eclipse, mybatis, dtd, mybatis-generator

I'm trying to use MyBatis Generator version 1.4.2 in Eclipse 2020-03 with Java 1.8.0_111. I just created a data base locally and trying to create some mappers from the config.xml:

> 

```
<!DOCTYPE generatorConfiguration PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD MyBatis Generator Configuration 1.0//EN" 
"http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-generator-config_1_0.dtd">
<generatorConfiguration>
 <classPathEntry location="C:\Users\.m2\repository\com\mysql\mysql-connector-j\8.0.31\mysql-connector-j-8.0.31-sources.jar"/>
      <context id="Comerzzia" targetRuntime="MyBatis3">
      
        <plugin type="org.mybatis.generator.plugins.CaseInsensitiveLikePlugin"/>
        <plugin type="org.mybatis.generator.plugins.RowBoundsPlugin"/>
      
        <commentGenerator>
            <property name="suppressAllComments" value="true"/>
        </commentGenerator>    
            
        <jdbcConnection connectionURL="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xxx" 
            driverClass="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
            password="fuego" 
            userId="xxxx" />
            
        <javaModelGenerator targetPackage="com.comerzzia.fundgrube.backoffice.persistence.lenguajes" 
            targetProject="backoffice-services/src/main/java" >
            <property name="enableSubPackages" value="false" />
              <property name="trimStrings" value="true" />
        </javaModelGenerator>
            
        <sqlMapGenerator targetPackage="com.backoffice.persistence.lenguajes" 
            targetProject="backoffice-services/src/main/java">
            <property name="enableSubPackages" value="false" />
        </sqlMapGenerator>
            
        <javaClientGenerator targetPackage="com.backoffice.persistence.lenguajes" 
            targetProject="backoffice-services/src/main/java" type="XMLMAPPER" >
            <property name="enableSubPackages" value="false" />
        </javaClientGenerator>
            
        <table tableName="d_lenguajes_tbl" domainObjectName="Lenguaje">
        </table>
     </context>
</generatorConfiguration>
```

Every time I run this I get some errors about accessExternalDTD not geting recognized. I saw in some forums that people try to add javax to their projects, but how can I add this javax to a pluging from Eclipse? Is there another way to solve this issue with MyBatis Generator?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That error usually means that there is xerces.jar (file name could vary) in the classpath (possibly as a dependency of another library or included in some old container). Removing/excluding xerces may resolve the error. If this does not help, please post the full stack trace.

Comment: Hi @ave, how can I exclude the xerces.jar in a pluggin from Eclipse? I mean, I'm using the MyBatis Generator directly from Eclipse. Just right clicking the flie and runing it with MyBatis Generator. If this case is possible, please can you share how can I exclude this xerces.jar from it? Thanks

Comment: Upgrade or remove the plugin if that's an option. Alternatively, you might be able to workaround the issue by configuring Launcher (see the "MyBatis Generator User's Guide" in the Eclipse Help).

Comment: MyBatis Generator does not support these versions of Eclipse and Java. The minimum Eclipse version is 2021-06 and minimum Java is Java 11. I don't know if that is the cause of these issues, but I would suggest upgrading to supported versions as a start.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was (as commented by Jeff) that my Eclipse version was not compatible with MyBatis.

To solve the issue, the solution was to easily switch to Eclipse version 2021-06.